# Exponential functions for generating primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that no polynomial with integer coefficients can give a prime for all integer values. Also, we have a lot of information on Prime-Generating Polynomial (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html) and Formula for primes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#A_function_that_represents_all_primes).

It will be interesting to check for exponential functions whether they generate primes are not. Mersenne primes and Fermat primes are well-known examples with base $2.$ Here is a big discussion on the generalization for the exponential function with base $2$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5323/infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-2nc-as-n-varies

There are few more exponential functions which generate prime numbers (Cullen primes, Woodall primes, Proth primes, Wagstaff primes etc).

My question is: Can we find some conditions when will $b^n+c, c<b; b,c,n \in \mathbb{N}$ give odd prime numbers (for instance $b=3$ and $c=2$ gives the expression $3^n+2$ and $5,11,83 \cdots$ are the primes of this form) or more generally when will $ab^n+c, c<b; a,b,c,n \in \mathbb{N}$ give odd prime numbers?

It is a straightforward condition that $b^n$ and $c$ (in more general case $ab^n$ and $c$) must have opposite parity.

Answer (score 2):

No such formula can give primes for all $n \in \mathbb N$ (except in the trivial cases $b= 1$).  Of course, to get more than one prime we need $b$ and $c$ coprime.  Now suppose $p = b^m + c$ is prime.  Then $p$ must be coprime to $b$.  Then by Fermat's little theorem $b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$, so $b^{m+p-1} + c \equiv b^m + c \equiv 0 \mod p$, and thus is not prime.

Whether a formula of this sort can produce infinitely many primes is an open question.